# Logout event not visible in Navigation Menu in Experience Builder

Tags: experience-builder-page, navigation-menu

I have added the Logout Menu Item in my Navigation Menu as:- Name: Logout1; Type: Event; Event: Logout and then save the Menu, but Logout1 menu item is not visible in the Theme Navigation Menu. So How can I make it visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menu item types- System Link (Experience Builder, Experience Workspaces and Setup) and Event (Login and Logout) are not meant for navigation menu components like Navigation Menu, Tile Menu.

Those are basically for the User Profile menu and even if we set it up for a Navigation Menu, utilized in the Navigation Menu component, those new menu item types will be hidden from Navigation Menu, Tile Menu, and other Navigation-related components.

But if the same Navigation Menu is getting utilized in the new [Customizable User Profile Menu](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.rss_customizable_user_profile_menu.htm&type=5) Component, those items will be rendered.

I have followed up on having the documentation updated with our team internally and will let you know as I have more inputs.

**UPDATE:**
The salesforce [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.rss_customizable_user_profile_menu.htm&type=5) has been updated to reflect "Menu item types system link and event display only in the Customizable User Profile Menu component."

Regards,

Salesforce Support

Comment: I'm creating custom Aura theme layout using forceCommunity:themeLayout  How to use the Customizable User Profile Menu component in custom Aura theme layout?